# CSS file load homepage only omit others drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I am trying to load a css file to the homepage only in drupal 7 and have gotten help in do that. Now I need to omit another css file only on the hompage. I thought I could add and else statement but that produced an error. here is the code from the template.php file.

```
function fource_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if($vars['is_front']) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/js/image_scale.js');
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/css/index_style.css');
  }
}
```

this is what I tried:

```
function fource_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if($vars['is_front']) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/js/image_scale.js');
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/css/index_style.css');
  }else{
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/css/main.css');
}
```

can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: It usually helps stating what error you get ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just missed the the closure for the else statement (missing a curly bracket). Change your code to the following:

```
function fource_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['is_front']) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/js/image_scale.js');
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/css/index_style.css');
  }
  else {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme','fource').'/css/main.css');
  } // <-- this is the bit you're missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way insidfe html.tpl.php. Anyone have a reason why this is a bad solution?

```
<?php print $styles; ?>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @import url(/sites/all/themes/PATH-TO-CSS);
    <?php if ($is_front):?>
        @import url(/sites/all/themes/PATH-TO-HOME-ONLY.css);
    <?php endif; ?>
</style>
```

Comment: Question is flagged `drupal`, not `php`.